# Call private method of Parent class using Child Object

Tags: java, inheritance, private

I need to call a private method present in `Parent` class and I have created a `Child` class that is extending `Parent` class. Now I want to call the private method which presents in `Parent` class by the object of `Child` class and without using reflection API. How can I do that?

And there is also permission that I can change the structure of `Parent` class.

```
class Parent{
  private void print(){
    System.out.println("Private Parent");
  }
}
class Child extends Parent{
}
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of [`private`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers).

Comment: if you want to do it really then you can make another public method in parent to call it's print method

Comment: A private method of `Parent` can have delicate state that might be dependent on its `public` methods and allowing you to call the private method of `Parent` can wreck _havoc_. So for the sake of good what's `private` should be kept `private` ;) I you understand what I mean.

Comment: Ask your friend what's the behavior in `Parent`'s private method that he/she wants to access? Think whether that behavior can be extracted in form of interface.

Comment: Yes you are correct that a private method can only be accessed inside the class but is there any way to call the private method within the Parent class using the child object.

Answer (score 3):

A `private` method can only be accessed from within the class (see, e.g., [Java's tutorial about access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)).

This rule can sometimes be circumvented by using reflection or bytecode manipulation, but in a straight forward way you simply cannot access a `private` method from a child class. If you have such a requirement, change it to be `protected`.

Comment: Yes you are correct that a private method can only be accessed inside the class but is there any way to call the private method within the Parent class using the child object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a `private` method from the child class. The `private` method is only visible to the class itself. Change the method to `protected` or `public` to do so.

Comment: Yes you are correct that a private method can only be accessed inside the class but is there any way to call the private method within the Parent class using the child object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to call the private method within the `Parent` class using the child object except reflection or using inner class.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I am aware you can do this - directly calling a *private* member of the superclass from a subclass - is if the subclass is nested inside the superclass. For example:

```
class Parent {
  private void parent() {}

  class Child extends Parent {
    private void child() {
      parent();
    }
  }
}
```

will compile. Note that if you wanted to make the `Child` class static, you'd have to make `parent()` static too.

Otherwise, you cannot do this - `private` means not accessible outside that class. You would need to make the method `protected` (or `public`) if you want it to be callable from subclasses. You might be well-served making it `final` too, in order to prevent it from being overridden in subclasses.

Comment: are you sure that we can create a static outer class because i dont think that we can make a outer class static. Please explain

Comment: I didn't say anything about making the outer class static. I said you'd have to make `parent()` - the method - static.

Comment: And of course, you could make the `Parent` class static if that were nested inside another class.